# How to optimize a UNION with a final ORDER BY/OFFSET

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination, union

I got a complex table on a webpage (with datatable.js) that use with 3 differents "sources". This datatable is paginated in the front, but the back is not.

I want to put a server processing of the pagination, my request works, but I want to optimize it:

```
SELECT toto, titi
FROM
    (SELECT toto, titi
    FROM S1

    UNION

    SELECT toto, titi
    FROM S2

    UNION

    SELECT toto, titi
    FROM S3)
ORDER BY titi, toto
OFFSET 50 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY
```

My real code is more complex, but you have the main idea of my problem here.

`S1`, `S2` and `S3` may have 1 000 000 rows each, but at the end I only need 50 rows, any idea on how I can make it more efficient?

Comment: Not sure you will be able to make this much faster.  Can you use `union all` instead?  That doesn't remove duplicates, but should be slightly faster...

Comment: The better way is to limit your query in each select query by 50, and union them. after all, limit them by 50 again.

Comment: Yes Muhammad, but I have an ORDER BY at the end, so I can't really know which line to filter before the UNION. Thx sgeddes, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have indexes on all three tables with the columns `(titi, toto)`.

```
create index ix1 on s1 (titi, toto);
create index ix2 on s2 (titi, toto);
create index ix3 on s3 (titi, toto);
```

Then the query could look like:

```
select * 
  from (
    select toto, titi from s1 order by titi, toto 
      fetch next (50 + 50) rows only
    union all
    select toto, titi from s2 order by titi, toto
      fetch next (50 + 50) rows only
    union all
    select toto, titi from s3 order by titi, toto
      fetch next (50 + 50) rows only
  ) x
  order by titi, toto
  offset 50 rows fetch next 50 rows only
```

In any case, your pagination strategy is quite inefficient for high values of `OFFSET`. My query above can make a difference nevetheless.

The key improvements over your query are:

- Using indexes on each table separately.
- Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` since it more efficient.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a solution, since the ORDER BY is global and the table S1, S2 and S3 are differents (your code as only one table S1).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it gives good advices.
But, the think is, in the real script, my "ORDER BY" is dynamic (the user choose it on the interface) and I got at least 10 columns (maybe more in the future), so I don't think I can really generate 10^10 indexes :) , it will burn my writing time.

Also, It's mb again not really answering my problem: the fetches of your smaller SELECTs are not selecting the good lines, since I want the 50 rows of the 2nd page of the FINAL table, which is not the same (S1, S2 and S3 have different data). Or... I still don't get the "50+50" trick :)

Comment: I think I got it now... I should had typed `OFFSET 500 ROWS FETCH NEXT 50 ROWS ONLY` to make the difference and understand it easily. I will try it !